# REST - java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm getting the IllegalStateException when I'm trying to invoke GET method and I have no idea what's wrong. You can see the log below.

https://pastebin.com/EC6CABcU - log

```
package com.medicalsystem.controller;

import com.medicalsystem.model.Admission;
import com.medicalsystem.service.AdmissionService;
import com.medicalsystem.service.PatientService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class AdmissionController {

    private AdmissionService admissionService;
    private PatientService patientService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/admission/{admissionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Admission> getAdmission(@PathVariable("admissionId") int admissionId) {
        if (!admissionService.exists(admissionId)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        Admission admission = admissionService.getById(admissionId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(admission, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/admission", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateAdmission(@RequestBody Admission admission) {
        admissionService.saveOrUpdate(admission);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Admission successfully added", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spotted this in your stack trace;  "Could not write JSON document: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)".  It's Jackson attempting to serialize a bidirectional relationship between disease and disease description. Jacksons annotation for @JsonIgnore may help, there's a good article [here] (http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion).

Comment: @GrumpyWelshGit Thank you! It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me the Admission is an Entity class.

```
import com.medicalsystem.model.Admission;

Admission admission = admissionService.getById(admissionId);
```

It is not a good practice to return Entity directly from your web service.
Since entities can be live and managed, any calls to the getter methods specially mapped fields will result in loading the related entities. And since the bean to json serializer will call all getter methods recursively to construct the json string, it will end up in a cyclic call when entities refer to each other. Which you can see clearly in the log (StackOverflowError)

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Create a Response Bean and define the fields to be returned and transfer the data that you need from the entity to the response bean.